# how to redirect to specific page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When filling out the form I want it to redirect me to another page but I can't get to the page.

**route**

```
Route::get('cotizacion-enviada', function () {
     return view('quotationshippingvalid');
})->name('cotizacion-enviada');
```

**controller**

```
public function store(StoreQuotationShipping $request){

    $data = $request->all();
    
    $id = QuotationShipping::create([
        'user_id' => $data['id'], //usuario alvaro por defecto
        'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
        'rut' => $data['rut'],
        'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
        'ciudad' => $data['ciudad'],
        // 'direccion' => $direccion,
        'sucursal' => $data['sucursal']
    ])->id;
     
    return redirect()->route('cotizacion-enviada', [$id]);
    
}
```

The information of the page appears but it redirects to the page, it stays on the same page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `return redirect()->route('cotizacion-enviada', [$id]);`, you can do 
 `response()->json(["redirect" => route('cotizacion-enviada', [$id])]);`

Then on your Vue app, check if your response has the key named `redirect` by using `obj.hasOwnProperty("redirect")`. And within the condition body, you may redirect to the route which you are sending from the controller method as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you need id in 'cotizacion-enviada' try this:

```
Route::get('cotizacion-enviada/{id}', function ($id) {
     return view('quotationshippingvalid', ['id' => $id]);
})->name('cotizacion-enviada');
```

If your route only render view file, you can render view inside your controller directly.